# WebSocket Failed When try to connect to a public ip

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, java-websocket

I'm doing a websocket with javax.websocket and a JavaScript client; when I call the websocket in JavaScript with a private IP it works, like this:

```
var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://10.3.3.25:8083/MyJavaWebSocket/MyEndPoint");
```

But when I try to change the IP for a public IP, it doesn't work:

```
var websocket = new   WebSocket("ws://190.168.10.10:8083/MyJavaWebSocket/MyEndPoint");
```

or

```
var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://mydomain.com:8083/MyJavaWebSocket/MyEndPoint");
```

It throws "failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404".

This is my Java server code:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/MyEndPoint", configurator = ChatServerEndPointConfigurator.class)
public class MyEndPoint {
    static Set<Session> sesionesUsuarios = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        sesionesUsuarios.add(session);
        System.out.println(session.getId() + " has opened a connection");
        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Connection Established");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("SEND MESSAGE");
    }


    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        sesionesUsuarios.remove(session);
        System.out.println("Session " + session.getId() + " has ended");
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm using apache-tomcat-8.0.33. Can anyone help shed some light on what is wrong here?

Comment: I think you have connected, a 404 implies that `/MyJavaWebSocket/MyEndPoint` could not be found however, can you verify that the endpoint is correct?

Comment: Yes, the endpoint is correct because, with the private IP it works, so the only thing that I changed was the IP, from private to public.

Comment: 190.168.10.10:8083 doesn't seem to be reachable as a public IP address from the public internet

Comment: Sorry i changed the real ip for security reasons.